# How to use asdf with haskell

Tags: asdf-vm

I would like to use the [asdf-haskell](https://github.com/vic/asdf-haskell) tool. I have installed [asdf-vm](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf), and I have installed `asdf-haskell`.

I have installed `ghc-8.4.3` and `ghc-8.6.5` by running `asdf install haskell 8.4.3` and `asdf install haskell 8.6.5`. The installs seemed to have worked, at least on the "asdf side". The contents of my directory `~/.asdf/installs/haskell` are as expected

However, when I am in a stack project, and I run `stack test`, stack goes ahead and downloads `ghc-8.6.5` again into the `~/.stack`. I was expecting it to use what was already downloaded to the `~/.asdf` directory. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with the asdf-haskell plugin, but it sounds like the `stack` command you are running might not be the one provided by asdf. Try running `type -a stack` and see what `stack` command is actually on your PATH. You can also run `echo $PATH` and see if the asdf shims directory is on your path as it should be. If you don't see the version of `stack` provided by asdf either:

- You don't have asdf installed correct and shims are not being added
  to your PATH (go back to the documentation website and repeat the [installation steps](https://asdf-vm.com/#/core-manage-asdf-vm?id=install)).
- Or the shims haven't been generated for some reason, in
  which case you can run `asdf reshim` to fix them.

Comment: Thank you - I think the problem is that asdf does not set the STACK_ROOT environmental variable, so stack is going to use "~/.stack" by default. It should instead something within "~/.asdf". There is an issue here: https://github.com/asdf-community/asdf-haskell/issues/18. This is only the case with the new version of stack.

Answer (score 0):

Could be the intended behaviour for stack as stated:

> The stack setup will download the compiler if necessary in an isolated location (default ~/.stack) that won't interfere with any system-level installations. (For information on installation paths, please use the stack path command.).

[Source](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) (under the ***Start your new project*** section)